# Magento 2 cookie is not set on homepage

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, cookie

I'm trying to set a new cookie the same way the store cookie is set.
I use the following plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\FrontController">
        <plugin name="homepage_plugin" type="My\Module\Model\Plugin\Hompage" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>
```

I have the following code that should set the cookie:

```
public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\FrontController $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $param = $request->getParam('___cookie');
        $cookie = $this->cookieManager->getCookie('cookie');
        $toSet = $param ? $param : $cookie;

        if (isset($param) && $param !== $cookie) {
            $metadata = $this->cookieMetadata
                ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
                ->setDurationOneYear()
                ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
                ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

            $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie('cookie', $toSet, $metadata);
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine on any other page except homepage. On homepage it seems that `beforeDispatch()` is called twice and the second time it's missing it's parameter on `getParam()`.

With full_page disabled the cookie is set correctly on homepage as well.